# How to determine the Business Unit for the Journey from Custom Activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, soap-api, custom-activity

Hello I've been digging through the internet on how I can retrieve or get the business unit of the currently running journey from the custom activity, basically I want to get the business unit from which this currently running journey is being run through to the custom activity.

I saw the token context solution but the problem with that is it relies on which business unit you did installed the app package your custom activity is using. This will not work because the app package is installed on the parent BU but will be available to all it's child BU's, so relying on the token context will just consistently give me the parent BU even though the custom activity is being run from one of the child BU.

I'm able to receive in the custom activity some information of the journey it's currently being run through, specifically the `journeyId`, `activityId`, `activityInstanceId`, `activityObjectID`, & `definitionInstanceId`, and I'm thinking maybe I can relate or use these information to get which BU does this journey is currently running or was created, etc.

In conclusion is there any way I could get or determine the business unit of the journey from the currently running custom activity.

Comment: What was your solution ?